# Creating an object in a static way

Tags: java, static

Could anyone explain how Java executes this code? I mean the order of executing each statement.

```
public class Foo
{
    boolean flag = sFlag;
    static Foo foo = new Foo();
    static boolean sFlag = true;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(foo.flag);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
false
```

Comment: We are human, not computer. Should we try to make code more straightforward rather than using these sort of tricks or traps or whatever...

Comment: +1 because it's not a difficult but good question, which I'm sure will help others in understanding the language and especially the static modifier better. Very useful answer given by @JonSkeet on a somewhat important - but often underestimated - topic.

Comment: I dislike it when people use 'Foo'.  Use real terms :/

Answer (score 104, accepted):

- Class initialization starts. Initially, `foo` is null and `sFlag` is false
- The first static variable initializer (`foo`) runs:

  - A new instance of `Foo` is created
  - The instance variable initializer for `flag` executes - currently `sFlag` is false, so the value of `flag` is false
- The second static variable initializer (`sFlag`) executes, setting the value to true
- Class initialization completes
- `main` runs, printing out `foo.flag`, which is false

Note that if `sFlag` were declared to be `final` it would be treated as a *compile-time constant*, at which point all references to it would basically be inlined to `true`, so `foo.flag` would be true too.

Comment: Does it matter the order in which the variables are defined in the class ? i.e. if `flag` was defined after `sflag`?

Comment: @Naveen IMHO, I don't think so. static variables will be initialized first.

Comment: @Naveen: The order matters in that if `sFlag` were declared before `foo`, that would matter - but `sFlag` and `flag` order doesn't matter.

Comment: static members are initialised in the order they are declared. If you declare    sFlag  before the instance is created then the output would be true.

Comment: @Jon, could you give a bit more info on why the value of ***foo.flag*** would have been true if ***sFlag*** was declared final? seems confusing to me since the assignment to ***flag*** always happens before the initilization of ***Sflag*** Thanks

Comment: @ClintHui: Compile-time constants have their constant values used wherever the constant field is referred to, rather than actually accessing the field... so it wouldn't matter that the field wasn't actually set to its value yet.

Answer (score 12):

`foo` is instantiated during the static initialization of the class, and before sFlag was initialized, and the default value of a boolean is false.

1. The class is loaded
2. Foo is initialized to the instance

   2.a The instance member flag is initialized to the value of sFlag (`false` by default)
3. sFlag is initialized to **true**

Please refer to [JLS §12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

When class is loaded, `sFlag` and `foo` fields are initialized but `foo` is initialized first!
fields `flag` and `sFlag` are boolean and can't be null so by default there're false and `sFlag` is still false when `foo` is being initialized. `flag = sFlag` after this `flag` is false.That's it

Answer (score 2):

The general order of initialization operations is (after the class is loaded and before first use):

1. Static (class) code blocks in order it appears in the code,
2. Object code blocks in order it appears in the code (initialization blocks and assignments).
3. Constructors

Certainly I don't refer constructors and functions body as a *code block* above .

I don't know how about `final static` fields. It looks like they follow the rules of `static` fields and they cannot be referenced before declaration despite previous comments that they are initialized at compilation step. If they are referenced before there is a compilation error:

```
Example.java:8: illegal forward reference
        System.err.println("1st static block j=" + j);
```

Maybe `final static` fields can be initialized and compiled into the class file but this is not a general rule and they still cannot be referenced before declaration.

Example code to check initialization order:

```
class Example {    

    final static int j = 5;

    {
        System.err.println("1st initializer j=" + j);
    }

    static {
        System.err.println("1st static block j=" + j);
    }

    static {
        System.err.println("2nd static block j=" + j);
    }

    final static java.math.BigInteger i = new java.math.BigInteger("1") {    
        {
            System.err.println("final static anonymous class initializer");
        }
    };

    Example() {
        System.err.println("Constructor");
    }

    static {
        System.err.println("3nd static block j=" + j);
    }

    {
        System.err.println("2nd initializer");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println("The main beginning.");
        Example ex = new Example();
        System.err.println("The main end.");
    } 
}
```

The above code snipset prints:

```
1st static block j=5
2nd static block j=5
final static anonymous class initializer
3nd static block j=5
The main beginning.
1st initializer j=5
2nd initializer
Constructor
The main end.
```

Comment: JVM specification [Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)

Answer (score 1):

at first static fields should run and at first inline! so at first line 4 and then 5 will run so foo is initialized first and as we know boolean variables are initialized to false by default so at first so as the foo is initialized the field of flag is sflag that's false and then sfalsg becomes true that won't change flag( there's no relation) then at last main runs and print falg that is false!!!
I hope to be useful! Be successful