# Java: Why no warning when referencing a field before it is defined?

Tags: java, static, initialization, inner-classes

A static field cannot be referenced before it is defined or initialized:

```
static Integer j = i; /* compile error */
static final Integer i = 5;
```

However, when it is referenced from an instance initialization block (in an anonymous inner class), not even a warning is generated.

See example:

```
class StaticInitialization {

    static final Object o = new Object() {{
        j = i;
    }};

    static Integer j, k;
    static final Integer i = 5;

    static final Object o2 = new Object() {{
        k = i;
    }};
}
```

The result is: `j == null`, `k == 5`, so clearly we've made a reference, order matters, and no warning or compilation error.

Is this code legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this code legal? Probably. I don't think it's the compiler's job to analyze your deliberate side-effects of object instantiation in buggering up static variables.

The limited analysis of 'declare before referencing' from other statics in the same class is really just a helper against the most common boo-boos, not a ironclad guarantee against indirect errors.

I'm really not at all surprised that the the "declare before referencing" analysis is limited in scope to direct access of static variables in other `static` declarations. This is a simple & compact analysis with minimal complexity & very fast.

Extending it to consider side-effects of object instantiation & method calls, OTOH, would require the 20-1000x greater weight & scope of *static program analysis*. Static analysis requires access to potentially the entire compiled program code, with constraint-based computation to determine what may possibly happen, and run-times potentially in the minutes.

Given these choices it is fairly easy, in the Java language designer's shoes, to choose *simple analysis* covering only direct accesses from fields within the same class.

Answer (score 1):

In the first block, you're not referencing a static field before it is initialized, but referencing before it is **defined** (as the compiler will tell you). This will work, for example:

```
static Integer j;
static final Integer i = j;
```

All fields have default values when not set explicitly (for objects, that's the `null` reference, for primitives, that's the corresponding sensible default, `0`, `false`, etc.). Therefore, the fields are always initialized so the compiler doesn't need to check for that.

Regarding `final`: it's really a modifier used for the benefit of the developer(s). As the [JSL states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html), `final` fields must be "definitely assigned" before access. That does not mean they would have no value otherwise (if it were not `final`), it just means that the compiler protects **you** against not assigning it explicitly, if it cannot find that assignment.

So, for non-`final` fields, you most definitely **can** reference them before an explicit assignment. Just paste the code snippet above to verify.

Comment: right, it would be before initialization in:

{
 final Integer i;
 final Integer j = i;
 i = 5;
}

 "The local variable i may not have been initialized"

Comment: but when referencing before initialization we get "The blank final field i may not have been initialized"

Comment: @user2622016 : added clarification.

Comment: OK, so:
* accessing uninitialized local variables - error, 
* accessing uninitialized class or instance variables - no error (too complicated for compiler to check), 
* accessing uninitialized final variable - sometimes error (in some cases compiler can be sure)

Comment: @user2622016 : * true, * true, but for a different reason (the compiler won't bother, since it's not required to check in this case), * false, error **unless** the compiler is sure you have initialized the **field**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that happens because first the space for all variables is allocated (and initialized with #0) and after that all the initialization is done in the order of your code.

Means, if you change the code like this:

```
    class StaticInitialization {

    static Integer j, k;
    static final Integer i = 5;

    static final Object o = new Object() {{
        j = i;
    }};

    static final Object o2 = new Object() {{
        k = i;
    }};
    }
```

The result is for all `variables == 5`.

Comment: "Why do you use }}and {{? One of them would be enough" .. nope! the inner ones are for the instance-initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is similar to this one:

```
class StaticInitialization
{
    static final Foo1 o = new Foo1();
    static Integer j, k;
    static final Integer i = 5;
    static final Foo2 o = new Foo2();

    class Foo1
    {
        public Foo1()
        {
            j = i;
        }
    }

    class Foo2
    {
        public Foo2()
        {
            k = i;
        }
    }
}
```

When you refer to `i` inside `Foo1`, `i` was null. However, `i` becomes `5` when you refer to it inside `Foo2`. Note that if `i` was a compile-constant (`i` is `int` not `Integer`), then `j` would be 5.

See this related question: [Creating an object in a static way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10613853/597657)

Answer (score 0):

The rules for `final` variables are quite different from all others. For example, for `final` variables the compiler *must* check if the variable has definitely been assigned once and *not* been assigned afterwards.

This is possible, because there are quite a few restrictions on `final` variables (which is pretty much the point of `final`).

Therefore, the in-depth analysis of "is this assigned before use" only really works within the limited world of final variables.

Comment: compiler _must_ check if is assigned exactly once, but definitely hasn't checked if it isn't referenced before the assignment

Answer (score 0):

This is defined in [JLS 8.3.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3).

> The declaration of a member needs to appear textually before it is
>   used only if the member is an instance.

That is why you are getting error when you do this..

```
static Integer j = i; /* compile error */
static final Integer i = 5;
```

But accesses by methods are not checked in the same way.

Comment: Try to elaborate more.